# What does "mod" mean in "$L(c_0,...,c_n \bmod a_1,...,a_m, b_1,...,b_m)$"?

Tags: notation

In Section 2.2 of Brent and Kung's ["Fast Algorithms for Manipulating Formal Power Series" (PDF link via harvard.edu)](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~htk/publication/1978-jacm-brent-kung.pdf), this notation appears: $$L(c_0,...,c_n \bmod a_1,...,a_m, b_1,...,b_m)$$

This "mod" does not appear to sound like something like $10=2 \bmod 8$. This $L$ is the number of operations to compute $(c_i)$ from $(a_i)$, $(b_i)$.

What is the abbreviation, "mod", here? Is it "modulo"?

Comment: I believe that the authors just mean to say that "$L$ is the number of steps to compute the $c's$ $\textit {given}$ the $a's$ and $b's$".  It's confusing, since elsewhere the authors use mod as a function to truncate formal power series.

Comment: Indeed, in the introduction the authors write:

"The composition problem is to compute $r_0 ..... r_n$,
given $p_l ..... p_n$ and $q_0 ..... q_n$".  Right after this, they define your function $L$...so "mod" is their way of saying "given", at least in this expression.  For whatever it's worth, I'd have preferred a notation like $L(c_i, \,|\,a_i, b_i)$